# Bootstrap less files: vertical-three-colors undefined

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, bootswatch

I have downloaded a nice [theme](http://bootswatch.com/spacelab/) from Bootswatch, but I would like to change some colors. So I got the **bootswatch.less** and **variables.less** and compiles a merged file using **WinLess**.

When I do this I get following error:

```
undefined #gradient > .vertical-three-colors
```

I have read an issue on github indicating that one should include: **bootstrap.import.less**

But I cannot find this in the bootstrap distribution.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Which theme did you download from Bootswatch? You should link to it in your question.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using? If Bootstrap 3 so you need to import `mixins/gradients.less`

Comment: Hi Neilhem. I use version 3.20 and I tried prepending gradidents.less. Now it says that .transitions are undefined. I know this approach is bad - but all I wish is to change a color or two without having to deal with git, grunt and all other kinds of acronyms, I dont know the meaning of :)

Comment: Hi Marco Del Vall, I have added a link to the Bootswatch Spacelab theme.

Comment: I guess the simplest way to do that (like I usually do this myself): create "my-whatever-bootswatch-theme-name.less" file, import *three* required files there (see example [gist](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/4ff8510d7be594f45ce5#file-25278043-less)) and compile it (the *only* file). That's it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the same problem with `_bootswatch.scss`.

After `yo angular` with `bootstrap-sass` just replace all text in main.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_gradients.scss";
@import "bootstrap.css";
@import "_variables.scss";
@import "_bootswatch.scss";
```

[angular](/questions/tagged/angular)[sass](/questions/tagged/sass)[bootswatch](/questions/tagged/bootswatch)[bootstrap-mixins-gradients](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-mixins-gradients)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to Gradient Mixins missing. Easy way to solve is the download latest source code of bootstrap and import

```html
@import "path\bootstrap-3.3.7\bootstrap-3.3.7\less\mixins\gradients.less";
```